# Don't wait for file_get_contents() to finish

Tags: php, multithreading, performance

Is there a way to call multiple `file_get_contents` without waiting first one to finish. I have a few PHP scripts that do some heavy work and execution time of one is more than 1.5 min so I want to call them all at the same time to reduce execution time. Currently I have multiple file_get_contents but to run next file_get_contents the first one needs to finish first. I tried `exec` method but it's blocked on server (shared hosting).

Comment: I'm not one to judge, but shared hosting and 90 second file_get_contents execution time. That's a recipe for overuse and having your hosting banned (against fair usage policy). I would suggest you investigate queuing requests and processing these evenly throughout the day via a CRON.

Comment: @JamieBicknell I agree, however if using shared hosting, CRON is certainly not available, so a custom  task queue is necessary.

Comment: I've not encountered any reputable shared hosting that doesn't allow CRON. They will however have restrictions like minimum run is once every 10 or 15 minutes, and maximum execution time of 60 seconds, but a decent shared host will have CRONs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are ways of running tasks in parallel if thats what you're trying to achieve but bare in mind PHP is a high level scripting language and the original purpose of it was to serve stateless HTTP request.

There are extensions out there like [Gearman](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php), this extension allows applications to complete tasks in parallel.

Obviously this will be in vane for you as you're probably using a service for just hosting. Get something like a vps, a vps from [OVH](https://www.ovh.co.uk/vps/) is cheaper than most web hosting services.

Comment: you mean vps, not vpn?

Comment: Yes sorry I mean a virtual private server

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible! But it is little bit tricky!

You have to play with `forks`.

I agree about queues and else... but just for the sake of ability, here is an example:

```
<?php

declare(ticks = 1);

$a = [
    'https://twitter.com',
    'https://facebook.com',
    'https://stackoverflow.com',
    'https://linkedin.com',
    'https://github.com',
];

// Count of php threads (forks or processes).
$max = 3;
// Child counter.
$child = 0;

pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, function ($signo) {
    global $child;
    if ($signo === SIGCLD) {
        while (($pid = pcntl_wait($signo, WNOHANG)) > 0) {
            $signal = pcntl_wexitstatus($signo);
            $child--;
        }
    }
});

foreach ($a as $item) {
    while ($child >= $max) {
        sleep(1);
    }
    $child++;
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if ($pid) {
    } else {
        // Child fork.
        sleep(1);
        // HERE YOUR CODE:
        echo file_get_contents($item);
        exit(0);
    }
}

while ($child != 0) {
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way in the code to limit the number of forks, for example if passed an array of 200 links, that's 200 simultaneous `file_get_contents` trying to work in parrallel, that's going to crawl.... `$max` doesn't appear to be used.

Comment: @Martin Yes, here present limit, and it is `$max`) and it is used: `while ($child >= $max) {`. In this example we have 3 threads.

Comment: @Martin np!) Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Your `while` all it's doing is waiting a second before carrying on, so doesn't appear to be limiting the number of executions of the forks (there would still be 200 calls, just spread over 196 seconds). If each `file_get_contents` call takes 1.25 seconds to complete then that will still cause a system drain

Comment: @Martin You can grab my simple example from here: https://github.com/cn007b/my/blob/master/ed/php/examples/thread.forkProcess.php and run it in shell, you will see how it works. I've already mention that it is little bit tricky)

Comment: @Martin Also in `htop` or `ps aux|grep thisScriptName` you can observe count of real processes...

Comment: Cheers for the info, I'm checking out the GitHub now

Comment: Nice answer but unfortunately 90% `pcntl` functions are disabled on hosting, I think it's time for VPS