# How to call file_get_contents() in PHP without waiting for result?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

In some of my PHP scripts I am using this code to `POST` data to a URL:

```
$file = @file_get_contents();
```

This will only `POST` data, content returned by server is empty. The executed script is really unimportant and isn't needed for the main script that gets executed. It's like a log file.

Normally PHP will wait until this is ready executed.

Is there a way to call `$file=@file_get_contents();` without waiting for the result? Just call it and execute the next command without taking care of `$file=@file_get_contents();`?

I have already searched for this problem but only found solutions for the console.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Maybe you want something like crons...!!?

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204936/dont-wait-for-file-get-contents-to-finish - the second answer there?

Comment: @boyd No, CronJobs aren't what I am looking for. `$file=@file_get_contents();` will get called every time a user opens the webpage. But it's something additional and unimportant I don't want the user to have to wait.

Comment: @DavidWinder Looks a tittle bit complicated but I'll take a look at it.

Comment: if you don't want to use CronJobs  then creating threads are the way to go, but they are tricky. You can also use a message broker like RabbitMQ to do that.

Comment: If your doing it last, you could just close the connection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273570/continue-processing-php-after-sending-http-response

Comment: here is a simply fire-and-forget POST function, so it won't wait for the response created by gr8gonzo 2012-07-18 : https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27795966/Asynchronous-file-get-contents.html

Comment: @SL5net That looks good. I'll take a look at it and try it. Thanks!

Comment: PHP can do threading. Loading data parallel is possibility. see: 
http://php.net/pthreads

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

**file_get_contents** is a sync method so you can't just skip it but if the method is not important a solution using PHP is create a thread and put it that log logic method, in that way you can run the process where actually the request is being attended (process / thread) and at "same time" the thread logging whatever you are doing.
http://php.net/manual/es/class.thread.php

Answer (score 1):

This feature is with `file_get_contents` not really possible. But you can use `fsockopen` to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the asynchronous code inside a separate PHP file, then execute it using one of the [program execution functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php). You need to spawn the program in such a way that PHP does not wait for it to finish. For example on Unix you can use the `&` operator:

```
<?php
shell_exec("php post.php arg1 arg2 arg3 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

This is tricky on Windows but not impossible.